# why can I get an uncommitted row?

Tags: mysql, transactions

In my code, I started a transaction, and inserted some data.

Then I could use `select` to fetch the rows which I inserted just now before transaction committing.
How did this happen?

My database is Mysql with Engine Innodb.

Thanks!

Comment: Because you are working under a transaction. That's how they work. What do you expect?

Comment: @skypjack .  the inserting wouldn't be done actually until the transaction commited. I want to know why I can fetch the data at that moment

Comment: Because probably you are executing your `SELECT` within the same transaction, thus your data actually exist even if not committed yet. Try to move the `SELECT` out from the transaction and you won't see them anymore.

Comment: @skypjack, Yes, sorry for my unclear expression.  It seems the transaction  work in a cache, and so do the selecting operation

Comment: It doesn't seem, it's how transactions work and it is not exactly a cache, but you can imagine something like that to better understand them. :-)

Comment: @skypjack,thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. Want you me add the comment as a response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98796/discussion-between-zuotao-chou-and-skypjack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, that's how transactions are meant to work.
Probably you are executing your `SELECT` within the same transaction you used to `INSERT` your data, thus those data actually exist in that transaction even if not committed yet.
You can try to move the `SELECT` in another transaction or use it as a standalone statement (that is still another transaction under the hood) and you won't see the data anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, this is how transactions work. The process that executes them 'sees' the results even if they haven't committed them yet. However, other processes will NOT see them until they are committed. (i.e. if another user is logged into the DB & queries the rows, they won't find them until after you actually commit them).

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL works in autocommit mode - in transcations all updating operations(INSERT/UPDATE/INSERT) are commited automatically. But you can use:

```
SET autocommit=0;
```

To know more details you may read documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

```
To disable autocommit mode explicitly, use the following statement:

SET autocommit=0;

After disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for InnoDB or NDB) are not made permanent immediately. You must use COMMIT to store your changes to disk or ROLLBACK to ignore the changes.

autocommit is a session variable and must be set for each session. To disable autocommit mode for each new connection, see the description of the autocommit system variable at Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.
```

Comment: This doesn't reply to the question.

Comment: You wrote: "the inserting wouldn't be done actually until the transaction commited". Because by default INSERT operation is autocommited so you can fetch data, if you set  autocommit=0 so you will not do this.

Comment: @Harlam ,that's not my question .sorry for my poor expression. I mean why i can fetch data before the transaction commited

Comment: @ZuoTao.Chou, ok. I'm sorry.